# Nested callbacks with Scrapy

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, nested

I want to scrape the webpage of the products of different brand in [a webpage that lists all brands I'm interested in](https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/). So I basically did a Scrapy scraper with a parser to parse the URLs of every brand it finds, which then calls a parser to find the URLs of their respective products. However this doesn't seem to be the right way to do nested callbacks. It returns me:

```
2020-11-27 15:03:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (referer: None)
2020-11-27 15:03:19 [sephora] DEBUG: parse: I just visited: https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/
url:  https://www.sephora.fr/ABSOL-HubPage.html
2020-11-27 15:03:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output

    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\DataScience\nosetime_scraper\nosetime_scraper\spiders\sephora.py", line 23, in parse
    yield scrapy.Request(url=base_url + url, callback=self.parse_brand(response))
  File "c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\learning\datascience\scr_env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 32, in __init__
    raise TypeError(f'callback must be a callable, got {type(callback).__name__}')
TypeError: callback must be a callable, got generator
2020-11-27 15:03:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-11-27 15:03:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 317,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 65639,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.416377,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 14, 3, 19, 346887),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27, 14, 3, 17, 930510)}
2020-11-27 15:03:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Here is my spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import json


class SephoraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sephora'
    allowed_domains = ['sephora.fr']
    start_urls = ['https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/']

    # rules = (
    #     Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    # )

    def parse(self, response):
        base_url = 'https://www.sephora.fr'
        self.log("parse: I just visited: " + response.url)
        urls = response.css('a.sub-category-link::attr(href)').extract()
        if urls:
            for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=base_url + url, callback=self.parse_brand(response))

    def parse_brand(self, response):
        self.log("parse_brand: I just visited: "+ response.url)
        for d in response.css('div.product-tile::attr(data-tcproduct)').extract():
            d = json.loads(d)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=d['product_url_page'], callback=self.parse_item(response))

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log("I just visited: "+ response.url)
        # item = {}
        # #item['domain_id'] = response.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').get()
        # #item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').get()
        # #item['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').get()
        # return item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most provide a reference to a function in callbacks, not a function call.

So in order to fix your problem proceed as follow in every case but with the proper callback:

`yield scrapy.Request(url=base_url + url, callback=self.parse_brand)`

See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider for an example.